# How to use ng-pattern to limit 10 number inputs separated by commas

Tags: angularjs, validation, ng-pattern, angularjs-ng-pattern

I want to enter in up to 10, 8 character length numbers in one text field all separated by commas. For example, 12345678,12345678,12345678,12345678.....

The only thing is the numbers can only be 8 characters at max and only up to 10 numbers entered at max. I have it to where I can keep entering numbers but I cannot get it to be with those limitations and I need help.

This is what I have right now: ng-pattern="/^([0-9\s])+(,[0-9\s]+)*$/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
^\d{1,8}(,\d{1,8}){0,9}
```

And works as follows, first, require 1-8 digits, optionally, require comma, 1-8 digits 0 to 9 times.

Comment: You are a life saver, thank you so much, it actually worked. I keep forgetting about the digits regex use. I'm still new to this and again thank you very much! For anyone else that has this problem, the full code is ng-pattern="/^\d{1,8}(,\d{1,8}){0,9}?$/"

Comment: No problem ar all :-)

Comment: I had another quick question: if I wanted to add leading zeros how can I do this? So say you put in 1234, the end output would be 00001234

Comment: You could try something like `number = 14;
console.log(("00000000" + number).substr(-8,8));` perhaps?